# VirtualBox pci passthrough freezes host

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, freeze

I used the following command to add a PCI wi-fi card to a virtualbox guest OS: VBoxManage modifyvm "16.04" --pciattach 0d:00.0@01:05.0

Thw guest OS (Ubuntu 16.04) recognizes the card (I can see it with lspci), then I went to aditional drivers to select bcmwl-kernel-source, and after a while my host OS freezes.

I had deactivated Wi-FI before I started the guest OS.